# Thread pool / futures proper approach?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a WebMvc rest api. One of my rest methods is a "long running task". My initial implementation took 100 seconds to complete on my test data.

My second approach was to break the test data into pages and use a thread pool. In my service layer, I have `private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);` and I submit to it with `List<Future<Page>> results = this.executor.invokeAll(pages);` This got it down to 45 seconds.

The question is about waiting for all the pages. I do need the pages to be in order for the final json response, so I'm doing:

```
        List<Future<Page>> results = this.executor.invokeAll(pages);

        for (Future<Page> result : results)
            result.get();
```

If I do that, I guess I don't really care about the order in which they *finish*, because they'll be in the right order in the original pages list.

But get() is a blocking call. Does that even make a difference in a webmvc rest api?

Comment: What do you mean by  "I do need the pages to be in order", does this mean executor should complete tasks sequentially(in-the-order in which tasks were submitted) ?

Comment: @sonus21 No, I just meant I need to have the final result in the original page order. They can finish in any order. I've updated the question a bit since sonarqube didn't seem to complain about ignoring the result of .get().

Comment: I'm not quite sure but from my understanding even though you have enqueued all tasks at once, `get` should not help you to get the pages in the order because the `get` method is just used to block to see if the given future has been completed or not.  And this will not have any side effect on your APIs response.

Answer (score 0):

I can [assure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) you that `invokeAll` returns a list of futures in the **same order** as the callables passed, i.e. the 3rd `Callable<Page>` in the passed `pages` list is the origin of the 3rd `Future<Page>` in the `results` list of futures.

> **Returns:** a list of Futures representing the tasks, in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list, each of which has completed

So far so good as long as you are okay you will have these accessible after *all* of them would return `true` on `Future::isDone`, there is no way to access the intermediate results using such method.

You can use muiltiple calls of `CompletableFuture::supplyAsync(Supplier<T>, Executor)` to get `List<CompletableFuture<T>>` and then with `CompletableFuture::thenAccept(Consumer<T>)` perform an action on completion while waiting for the other results.

A minimal sample using a `String` instead of `Page` for sake of brevity:

```
Random random = new Random();
// simulate irregular delay
List<Callable<String>> pages = List.of(
    () -> { Thread.sleep(random .nextInt(3000)+2000); return "one";},
    () -> { Thread.sleep(random .nextInt(3000)+2000); return "two";},
    () -> { Thread.sleep(random .nextInt(3000)+2000); return "three";},
    () -> { Thread.sleep(random .nextInt(3000)+2000); return "four";},
    () -> { Thread.sleep(random .nextInt(3000)+2000); return "five";}
);

ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
List<CompletableFuture<String>> results = pages.stream()
    .map(callable -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
        // this should be wrapped into a method instead
        () -> { try {return callable.call();} catch (Exception ignore) {} return null; },
        executor))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// clumsy index print to demonstrate the immediate results
for (int i=0; i<results.size(); i++) {
    int index = i;
    results.get(i).thenAccept(page -> System.out.println("Finished (" + index + ") : " + page));
}
```

Unfortunatelly, the creators seem wanted to avoid any usage of checked exceptions while designing `CompatibleFuture`, therefore it is not compatible with `Callable<T>`.

Comment: So at the end of the day, you are still calling .get() to block. If I switch this service to webflux, can do something cooler at that point I guess.

Comment: Yea, Spring Webflux is cool. Btw. where I am calling `get()` to block? I have no idea how the OP wants to process the results so I provided a simple snippet using a consumer.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I misread the code, you were doing get() on the list. I'm the OP :). I need to return the results in my rest mvc call via json. So I need to put the results together when all are done, so it does need to be a blocking call at some point. My comment about Webflux was that I could have made it a mono/flux and not blocked at all, but for webmvc, I need to block somewhere.

Comment: When all are done != blocking. You practically *wait* until *all* of them are done, which assures either a call of `Future::isDone` or through fluent API using `CompletableFuture`. As long as you already develop on Spring, I suggest you to use Spring Webflux which IMHO handles such things much better (including blocking delayed as late as possible).